# Computer takes two tries to boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

I recently upgrade my computer's GPU, PSU, CPU fan and memory. And oddly it seems to be booting twice from a cold start. Here is what I upgraded:

1. GPU from GTX 560 Ti to GTX 770
2. PSU from generic brand to Corsair CX Series 750 Watt ATX/EPS Modular 80 PLUS Bronze
3. CPU fan from intel stock fan for i5 2500k to Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO - CPU Cooler with 120mm PWM Fan
4. Memory from 8GB to 20GB, although I know now only 16GB is usable [as explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/811456/installed-ram-20-gb-16-gb-usable).

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium and my MB spec can be seen [here](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8P67_LE/specifications/).

Also, I've updated my SSD (for OS) to the latest firmware.

So after the upgrade, I noticed my computer takes two tries to boot from a cold start (not restart). So when I press the power button, it tries to boot for a few secs (I can hear it starting up, CPU fan is on, etc.), then shuts down. Then a few secs later it tries to boot again and is successful.

What's causing this double boot? How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this happen every time, or has it only been once?

Comment: Post upgrade every time I boot from cold

Comment: Does it complete the BIOS POST before it reboots (does it beep)?

Comment: First try no beep, second try yes

Comment: Then information in the BIOS is being changed every time from a cold start. You can reconfigure the BIOS so it only needs to go through once. My best guess is that the hard drive or GPU needs to be configured differently. If it still has this problem, you may need to upgrade the BIOS.

Comment: @LDC3 upgraded the bios and that did the trick, don't know why but it worked.  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information in the BIOS is being changed on the first pass with a cold start. You can reconfigure the BIOS so it only needs to go through once.

My best guess is that the hard drive or GPU needs to be configured differently.

If it still has this problem, you may need to upgrade the BIOS.

Comment: Sometimes, a simple "reset to default" in BIOS settings can fix it. Other times, it takes going through every possible setting until it's fixed.

Comment: I was able to fix it by upgrading my bios, thanks!